# Configure Tkinter button add command not update

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I have a little problem. I have a module where I create some widgets.

My code button widget is down:

```
class lbl_button():    
    def __init__(self,container,valori,c,user_activ,parent_wnd):
        for key in valori :
            if key=='row':
                self.row=valori[key]
            if key=='column':
                self.column=valori[key]
            if key=='identificator':
                self.identificator=valori[key]
            if key=='text':
                self.btn_text=valori[key]
            if key=='clmn_span':
                self.clmn_span=valori[key]
            if key=='row_span':
                self.row_span=valori[key]
            if key=="cmd":
                self.comanda=valori[key]
        self.container=container
        self.cursor=c
        self.user_activ=user_activ
        self.paren_wnd=parent_wnd
        self.addcomponents()                  
    
    def addcomponents(self): 
        self.btn=tk.Button(self.container,font=('Comic Sans MS',7),text=self.btn_text,
                           foreground='white',bg=init.m_color)
        self.btn.grid(row=self.row,column=self.column,padx=3,pady=3,sticky='ew',columnspan=self.clmn_span,
                      rowspan=self.row_span)  
        self.btn.configure(command=lambda : self.trig())
```

I call this button in another module, and I want to reconfigure "command" like this:

```
if isinstance(i,design.lbl_button):
    if i.btn_text=="Importa ANAF":  
        i.btn.configure(command=self.get_bilant_anaf)
    print(i.btn.__dict__)
```

My problem is that: tclCommands': ['1974120001344<lambda>', '1974119064064get_bilant_anaf']}.

My button "command" is not updated, just add another command.

Comment: It is an internal design issue of `tkinter`, but it does not affect the behaviour since the previosuly configured command will not be executed.